# SVG image renders incorrectly when scaled

Tags: graphics, scaling, svg

I have exported a chemical structure as a SVG using MarvinSketch, and included it like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}

\includesvg[width=0.5\linewidth]{test.svg}

\end{document}
```

However, the font changed from Arial to Computer Modern, and the letters were not scaled along with the structure:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: There might be an option in MarvinSketch to export text as curves/paths, or otherwise you could open the svg in Inkscape and export from there. Otherwise you could try to export as pdf and include that in your LaTeX file.